# PHP post limit? Other mysql issue?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've been searching around for a solution, but each one I've found seems to not be helpful, I'm not actually sure whats causing the issue.

If I run the below mysql, this inserts a record into the database.

```
INSERT INTO cust_v_lists (Customer_name, Customer_ref) VALUES ('wouldja', 133)
```

What my program is currently doing is creating the above statement using parameters from page 1, then posting the mysql to page 2. On page 2 my code is simple.

```
$mysqli = $_POST['sqli'];
echo $mysqli; #this echo's out the above SQL insert line.
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $mysqli);
$updated = mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
$message = "You have inserted $updated row to the 'cust_v_lists' table.";
echo $message;

if (!mysqli_query($conn, $mysqli))
{
    echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

If I hard code the below:

```
 $sqli = ;INSERT INTO cust_v_lists (Customer_name, Customer_ref) VALUES ('wouldja', 133)';
```

This works fine, but when I post it I get the error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL     server version for the right syntax to use near '
INSERT INTO cust_v_lists (Customer_name, Customer_ref) VALUES ('w' at line 1
```

I first thought this was a post limit or something to 40 chars, but when I echo out the mysqli posted it seems ok, I changed the limits in php.ini just in case but this didn't help. I then updated this to a string using $mysqli = (string)$mysqli but this also didn't help. Has anyone seen this before? I don't want to hard code this, I need the query to be completely dynamic and readable from $_POST.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$sqli = ;INSERT INTO cust_v_lists (Customer_name, Customer_ref) VALUES ('wouldja', 133)';`

needs to be

`$sqli = "INSERT INTO cust_v_lists (Customer_name, Customer_ref) VALUES ('wouldja', 133)";`

Comment: Hi Magictallguy, thanks for replying. The sql is being posted as     INSERT INTO cust_v_lists (Customer_name, Customer_ref) VALUES ('wouldja', 133), is this incorrect?

Comment: That query is fine. Look at the difference between the 2 lines I posted ;)

Comment: Thanks again Magictallguy for replying, the issue was the query indeed. I should go back to school. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this insert statement

```
$sqli = "INSERT INTO cust_v_lists (Customer_name, Customer_ref)
         VALUES ('wouldja',133)";
```

Comment: Hi Nagaraj, thanks for replying. The sql is being posted as INSERT INTO cust_v_lists (Customer_name, Customer_ref) VALUES ('wouldja', 133), is this incorrect?

Comment: Any ideas how to determine what is causing the issue?